# Plot3d: How to color a surface according to the slope of the surface?

Tags: plotting

Here is my approach, for an example surface function:

```
surface[x_, y_] := Sin[x y];
```

The normal vector of a point in the surface is computed as:

```
NormalVector[a_, b_] := {D[surface[xx, yy], xx], D[surface[xx, yy], yy],1} /. {xx -> a, yy -> b};
```

Then the plot is as follows:

```
Plot3D[surface[x, y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 
RGBColor[0, 0, VectorAngle[NormalVector[x, y], {0, 0, 1}]]]]
```

However it fails, why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be honest, I'm not really sure why you need `ColorFunctionScaling` since there aren't any outlayers that could make the rest of the plot flat, nevertheless:

```
Plot3D[surface[x, y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
          Lighting -> "Neutral", ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 
          Blend[{Blue, White}, 2 #/Pi] &@ VectorAngle[NormalVector[x, y], {0, 0, 1}]]]
```

[image]

**Update**

```
Plot3D[surface[x, y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
         ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Blend["Rainbow", Rescale[#, {0, Pi/2}]
                                  ] & @ VectorAngle[NormalVector[x, y], {0, 0, 1}]], 
         PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 90}},  ColorFunctionScaling -> True,  
                                  LegendLabel -> "normal vs zenith [\[Degree]]"]
      ]
```

[image]

Comment: @Kuba.Aha! But is there a way to assign more color to the different slope values. It looks a bit dull.

Comment: @novice Of course, take a look at [`Blend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Blend.html?q=Blend&lang=en) or [`Color Schemes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ColorSchemes.html). Try for example `Blend["Rainbow", #] &@`

Comment: @KubaThank you, I tried and made it.

Comment: @KubaAnother small problem is that PlotLegends -> Automatic fails.

Comment: @novice ok, see my edit.

Comment: @Kuba thank you for illustrating `BarLegend`: very instructive

Answer (score 9):

Just for variety:
Note also outward normal to surface $z=f(x,y)$: $\nabla(z-f(x,y))=<-f_x,-f_y,1>$ (inward negative)...not same as "NormalVector" function listed (apologies if I have misinterpreted or made error).
I have rewritten taking into  account:

```
f[x_, y_] := Sin[x y];
n[x_, y_] := {-D[f[a, b], a], -D[f[a, b], b], 1} /. {a -> x, b -> y};
va[x_, y_] := VectorAngle[n[x, y], {0, 0, 1}];
Manipulate[
 Show[Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
   ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z}, 
     ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[va[x, y], {0, 1.4}]]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], 
  Graphics3D[{Red, Thick, 
    Arrow[{{s[[1]], s[[2]], 
       f[s[[1]], s[[2]]]}, {s[[1]], s[[2]], f[s[[1]], s[[2]]]} + 
       Normalize@n[s[[1]], s[[2]]]}, 0.03]}],
  ContourPlot3D[{x - s[[1]], y - s[[2]], z - f[s[[1]], s[[2]]]}.n[
      s[[1]], s[[2]]] == 0, {x, s[[1]] - 0.2, 
    0.2 + s[[1]]}, {y, -0.2 + s[[2]], 0.2 + s[[2]]}, {z, -2, 2}, 
   Mesh -> False]], {s, {0.1, 0.1}, {3, 3}}]
```

The graphic illustrates color of surface based on angle between normal and $\vec{k}$ (which seems to be intended color function). I show the  unit normal and tangent plane.

[image]

Comment: @ubpdqn__Yes, it is my fault. The upward normal should be ∇(z−f(x,y)). Thanks for reminding. Nice illustration.

Comment: @novice...just wanted to clarify...thanks