# Wrong BarLegend with VisibleSpectrum

Tags: legending

```
Plot3D[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"][
     Rescale[#3, {0, 1}, {380, 750}]] &), PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

There is no legend in this picture.

```
Plot3D[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"][Rescale[#3, {0, 1}, {380, 750}]] &), 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"VisibleSpectrum", {0, 1}}]]
```

[image]

```
BarLegend["VisibleSpectrum"]
```

[image]

The color of lengend is wrong.

Mathematica 10.0.1. Is this a bug?

Comment: I think the correct usage of the second argument should be `BarLegend[{"VisibleSpectrum", {380, 750}}]` but no, that doesn't work either...

Comment: related: [38895](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38895/5478). @Pickett almost :) see my answer.

Comment: @Kuba wow, I only tried `BarLegend` on its own. You can't even set the scaling then as far I as I know. I count this as a bug..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
f@x_ := ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"][Rescale[x, {0, 1}, {380, 750}]]; 
Plot3D[
 Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
 ColorFunction -> f, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{f@# &, {0, 1}}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I'm trying to perform your suggestion in a similar problem. However, here I'm using StreamDensityPlot instead of Plot3D. Therefore, my bar refers to the absolute value of the vector, i.e., ColorFunction -> (ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"][
    Rescale[#5, {0, 1.2}, {380, 750}]] &). How could I adjust your code accordingly?