# Inconsistent behavior in ColorFunctionScaling of BarLegend in v10.0.1

Tags: color, legending

I find the `ColorFunction` in `BarLegend` behaves very weirdly:

1. **Force rescaling from 0 to 1**

   For example:

   ```
   cf1[z_] := ColorData[{"Temperature", {0, 1}}][z];
   BarLegend[{cf1[#] &, {0, .5}}]
   ```

   gives
   [image]
2. **Rescaling changes within `MatrixPlot`**

   For example:

   ```
   MatrixPlot[RandomReal[{1, 4}, {10, 10}],
   PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Temperature", {1, 4}}],
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"Temperature", {1, 4}}][#] &),
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, DataReversed -> True]
   ```

   gives
   [image]
3. However, **generating `BarLegend` alone** as follows:

   ```
   BarLegend[{"Temperature", {1, 4}}]
   ```

   gives
   [image]

Obviously, `ColorFunctionScaling` in `BarLegend` has been set to `False` accordingly as in `MatrixPlot`, which is unexpected since I have no control of the scaling inside `BarLegend`.

### Questions:

Is the auto-rescaling a bug?
Or, how can I "utilize" the feature?

Comment: closely related: [5478](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66430/5478)

Comment: @Kuba,please don't close this thread. Although this question is related to what you posed, the problem behind the question still exists. At least, this behavior is very unexpected according to the official documentation.

Comment: Hi @Kuba, I mistakenly read your comments as "closed":P

Answer (score 2):

```
MatrixPlot[RandomReal[{1, 4}, {10, 10}],
 PlotLegends ->  BarLegend[{ColorData[{"Temperature", {1, 4}}], {1, 4}}],
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"Temperature", {1, 4}}]),
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, DataReversed -> True]
```

Version 9.0.1.0:

[image]

Version 10.0.1.0 (Wolfram Programming Cloud):

[image]

**Update:**  `PlotLegends ->    BarLegend[{ColorData[{"Temperature", {1, 4}}], {1, 4}}, 10]` does not work as expected to add contours in the bar legend; it rescales the tick labels to `{0,1}`. A work-around is to use `Legended`:

```
Legended[MatrixPlot[RandomReal[{1, 4}, {10, 10}],
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"Temperature", {1, 4}}]),
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, DataReversed -> True], 
 BarLegend[{ColorData[{"Temperature", {1, 4}}], {1, 4}}, 10]]
```

[image]

**Update 2:** version 11.3 (Wolfram Programming Cloud)

```
$Version
```

> "11.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (February 20, 2018)"

```
 MatrixPlot[RandomReal[{1, 4}, {10, 10}],
  PlotLegends ->  BarLegend[{ColorData[{"Temperature", {1, 4}}], {1, 4}}],
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"Temperature", {1, 4}}]),
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, DataReversed -> True]
```

[image]

Use `BarLegend[{ColorData[{"Temperature", {1, 4}}], {1, 4}}, 10]` to get
[image]

Comment: Hi @kguler, if I want to add nicely-divided contours in the `BarLegend`, how to do it? I tried: `MatrixPlot[RandomReal[{1, 4}, {10, 10}], 
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[{ColorData[{"Temperature", {1, 4}}], {1, 4}}, 10], 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"Temperature", {1, 4}}][#] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, DataReversed -> True]`. However, this will again be rescaled to `{0,1}`.

Comment: @sunt05, i get the same issue with version 9.0.1. A work-around is to use `Legended`. I will post an update in a moment..

Comment: Hi @kguler,  `Legended` does work for this scenario. But I seriously consider this as a bug, at least very vague usage as stated in the documentation.

Comment: @sunt05, i agree.

Comment: thanks for your answer anyway, @kguler. Let's see if someone from WRI will clarify this.

Comment: I am with MM11.3 and it seems this issue has not been solved. Can somebody can confirm?