# Color a Function by its Derivative

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, color

Mathematica's ColorFunction seems to struggle with coloring a function "y" by its derivative D[y,x]. This is a seemingly simple task, but Mathematica can't handle it. While I can certainly evaluate the derivative outside of the ColorFunction, that then makes plotting several functions with the same command difficult.

For Example:

```
Plot[{x^2, Sin[x]}, {x, -1, 1}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y},ColorData["NeonColors"][y]]]
```

Generates a plot of x^2 and Sin[x] colored by their y values.

```
Plot[{x^2,Sin[x]}, {x, -1, 1}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y},ColorData["NeonColors"][D[y,x]]]]
```

Returns an error. Any suggestions?

Edit for Mr. Wizard, this workaround works but involves separately finding the derivative of each function and showing the two plots together:

```
Show[Plot[x^2, {x, -1, 1}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["NeonColors"][2 x]]],Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 1},ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["NeonColors"][Cos[x]]]], PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Would you include the work-around that produces the result you desire?

Comment: [related 3d version](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38893/5478)

Answer (score 5):

CORRECTED for scaling.

```
f1[x_] = x^2;
f2[x_] = Sin[x];

Show[
 Plot[f1[x], {x, -1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["DarkRainbow"][f1'[x]]]],
 Plot[f2[x], {x, -1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["DarkRainbow"][f2'[x]]]],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

However, since the the documentation states that the x values fed to `ColorFunction` are scaled to {0,1} the unscaled x values would be

Show[
 Plot[f1[x], {x, -1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["DarkRainbow"][f1'[2 x - 1]]]], 
 Plot[f2[x], {x, -1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["DarkRainbow"][f2'[2 x - 1]]]], 
 PlotRange -> All]

[image]

Comment: Isn't this what the OP says she/he wants avoid?

Comment: @Michael - AFAIK `ColorFunction` takes only one argument so if each curve is to be colored by its derivative there needs to be two `Plot` calls. And I did not calculate the derivative outside of the `ColorFunction` which is what he wanted to avoid.

Comment: That's pretty much the way I see how `ColorFunction` works, too.  Since the OP seems to know how to color the individual graphs already, I figure an answer should explain why there is no other workaround.  Unless there is one, of course.

Comment: Couldn't you use `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` to get around this?

Comment: @DavidZ - that is valid approach. The one I used is somewhat shorter code.

Comment: Yes, though if I understand correctly, the approach in this answer needs to be manually modified to match the plot range in each case. Setting `ColorFunctionScaling` does the same thing but with the same syntax in every case.

Comment: I hoped for an answer like those of Chip Hurst or kguler. Both seem generalizable to the extent that I won't have to individually find the derivative of each function used. Thank you for reminding me to consider ColorFunctionScaling, but showing two separate plots together is something I could already do.

Answer (score 2):

Post-processing `Lines` to add `VertexColors` that depend on the value of the derivative:

```
funcs = {x^2, Sin[x]};
plt = Plot[funcs, {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Thick, ImageSize -> 400];
plt2 = Block[{j = 1, k}, Normal[plt] /. Line[z_] :> 
       (k = j++; Line[z, VertexColors -> (ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ 
            ((D[funcs[[k]], x] /. x -> #) & /@ Rescale[z[[All, 1]]]))])];

Row[{plt, plt2}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

**Update:** Dealing with `Plot3D` following @MichaelE2's suggestion in the comments: *use the `VertexNormals` as a basis for `VertexColors`:*

```
ClearAll[dF, showF];
dF[k_: 1] := # /. HoldPattern[VertexNormals -> vn_] :>
     {VertexNormals -> vn, VertexColors -> (ColorData["Rainbow"] /@Rescale[vn[[All, k]]])} &;
showF[k_: 1] := Show[(Plot3D[#, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
         Mesh -> None, ImageSize -> 350, BoxRatios -> 1] // dF[k]) & /@ #,
    PlotRange -> All, Lighting -> "Neutral"] &;
```

Example:

```
funcs = {x^2 + y^2, Sin[x + y^2]};
Row[showF[#]@funcs & /@ {1, 2, 3}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, that's what I was going to do! :)  Just couldn't get back to it.... +1

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's a shame that Mathematica requires such a complex procedure to acquire a seemingly simple result. I can certainly use your method, but this doesn't seem generalizable to Plot3D, which would be nice.

Comment: @Shaggy1135, good question. I think the approach suggested by Bob is more straightforward and it can be made to work for `Plot3D` too.

Comment: @Shaggy1135 In one way `Plot3D` is easier: One can use the `VertexNormals` as a basis for `VertexColors`.

Comment: @MichaelE2, thank you again.

Comment: Corrected: It might be worth pointing out that the normals are normalized: `vn` is a list of $(−f_x,−f_y,1)/\sqrt{f_x^2+f_y^2+1}$. The gradients $(f_x, f_y)$ are given by `-vn[[All, 1;;2]]/vn[[All, 3]]` and so forth.  (You're welcome, and sorry for the typo earlier.)