# Plot vectorfield and scalarfield in one graphic

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a scalar-field $f(x,y) = \frac{sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$ and it's gradient-field $\nabla f(x,y)$ in one graphic. Something like "StreamDensityPlot" in 3D. The mesh-lines on the scalar-field should look like arrows which are showing in the direction of the gradient.
Thanks very much :)

Comment: related: [Plot3d: How to color a surface according to the slope of the surface?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38893/5478)

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on rewi's answer if you want the 3D result:

```
    f[x_, y_] := Sin[x^2 + y^2]/(x^2 + y^2)

    sdp =
     StreamDensityPlot[  Evaluate[{Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}], f[x, y]}], {x, -3,3}, {y, -3, 3},  PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> False]
```

[image]

```
    Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Texture[sdp], Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

**Edit: Is there a bug with using `StreamStyle` with `Texture`?**

```
    sdp = StreamDensityPlot[
      Evaluate[{Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}], f[x, y]}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
      PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> False, 
      ColorFunction -> "SolarColors",
      StreamStyle -> White
    ]
```

[image]

The styling isn't carried over:?

```
    Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All, 
     PlotStyle -> Texture[sdp], Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

But if we use `StreamColorFunction`:

```
    sdp = StreamDensityPlot[
      Evaluate[{Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}], f[x, y]}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
      PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> False, 
      ColorFunction -> "SolarColors",
      StreamColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[1] &)
    ]
```

[image]

```
    Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All, 
     PlotStyle -> Texture[sdp], Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much :) How can I change the colour of the scalarfield and the arrows ?

Comment: If you look up `StreamDensityPlot` you'll find many options and examples of changing the various colors and stylings. You have to change them in the  `StreamDensityPlot`, not the `Plot3D` as the former is used as a texture map for the later. I'll add an example to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
f = Sin[x^2 + y^2]/(x^2 + y^2);
StreamDensityPlot[Evaluate[{Grad[f, {x, y}], f}], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: I want exactly this in 3D :)