# How do I use manipulate to move around a tangential plane?

Tags: manipulate

I am given the function `f[x, y] = x^2 + y^2`. I then have to plot the planes that are tangent to this surface at certain points. I have no problem with that, but I am then asked to use Manipulate to create an interactive plot where the tangential plane moves as I move the slider. How do I do this?

Comment: You might want to look up `Slider2D[]`.

Comment: What have you done, where are you stuck?

Comment: OP does not respond but instead of closing it as plain off topic I will link an answer which seems to do what OP wanted. The full topic is not very related but the second answer is: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38900/5478